# WebAPI [Authorize] returning error when logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to set up a `WebAPI` with `MVC5` / `Web Api 2`, it's currently using default configurations and other defaults right now. When I log in with an account in the browser, I can go to regular `MVC` controller actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute just fine, such as the Home page shows as it should when authorized, but then if I go to `/api/Me` (a default built-in api controller action) or any custom api controller action I've built with the default MVC Web Api 2 scaffolding that requires authorization, I get an error like so:

```
{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

This is when I'm trying it in Microsoft Edge, I haven't tried it on my actual client code I'm building yet, which is a `UWP` app. I figured I would test in the browser first to ensure things are working properly.

I started looking at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api It seems to be more geared towards `Ajax` requests and `SPAs` though. My goal is having things working through both the web and through `UWP`. I will probably focus more time on the `UWP` side than developing a robust web app with ajax, since the app will run in an intranet and access an intranet IIS server running the web api, I'd like to build a desktop client in UWP and eventually Xamarin that access data through Web Api.

Is it safe for me to assume that if you're using a regular web browser like Edge you cannot access Web Api controller actions when they are secured through the `[Authorize]` attribute, since it doesn't send an access token in the header?

Comment: Well John, how are you sending the authorization token from your client to your authorized action? Regardless of which client it is, MVC or UWP or Javascript client you need to send the token in the Authorization header to your api using either HttpClient (MVC, UWP) or using ajax, jquery etc if javascript client

Comment: You can test your authorized endpoint using a proxy tool such as postman or Fiddler and when you create the request add the Authorization header with your token in it

Comment: So right now in my UWP app, I'm doing a GET on /Account/Login to get the page first so I can get the Anti-forgery token. I'm parsing that out via Regex as I had trouble finding a Html DOM library in UWP (without going 3rd party) unless I'm looking in the wrong place. At that point I still need to get a bearer token I suppose to hit Web Api with Authorize and I'm not sure what to do for that yet.

Comment: You dont need an Anti forgery token for get requests, thats when you are posting data to your api

Comment: I should add that I was posting back via POST to log in, but that logs in through MVC. I'm thinking I must need to authenticate via Web Api, but not sure what's the endpoint and how to construct the http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from your UWP app you could create a couple of methods such as below, or may be wrap them up in a class that you can inject through DI (your choice).

```
public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string uriString) where TResult : class
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Log.Error(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return default(TResult);
            }
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
        }
    }

    public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult, TInput>(string uriString, TInput payload = null) where TInput : class
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Log.Error(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return default(TResult);
            }
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json);
        }
    }
```

And if you are using basic (username and password authentication) then your GetHttpClient method will be something like:

```
private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var username = // get username;
        var password = // get password;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
```

or if you are using bearer token then you could do:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer ", "string token goes here...");
```

Comment: I havent tested this code on UWP platform, but I am sure you do have access to the HttpClient class. So you could do something on similar lines. You might need to find the appropriate classes

Comment: Thanks, still having trouble on the getting the Token though. So in Postman I try pointing to http://localhost:55970/Token with a POST, using username and password, along with grant_type = "password" that was mentioned in the article, as x-www-form-urlencoded. I get back a json with {"error":"invalid_client"}. I'm not sure what I need to set in order to get it to recognize the client.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Have been rather busy. Have you tried to debug your Authorization Provider code?

Comment: I did, I needed to override the client validation and resource granting methods. I left off yesterday with getting the token, today I'll test that I can use the token to get data from the api.

Comment: Perfect. Let me know how you get on

Comment: Works perfectly in Postman. I also set client_id in the authentication request so that I identify a client in ValidateClientAuthentication, that way in my code I can check against a set number of clients that I've defined as able to access my web api. This adds an extra layer of security that I can use in my client apps (Xamarin, UWP). I also set grant_type = password, and un/pw. Once I've got the token, send it back as a authorization header: "Bearer (access_token)", now I get the desired result back.

Comment: What baffles me a little is that Microsoft hasn't provided a default implementation with the stock ApplicationOAuthProvider. They default to failures if you don't specifically override them, which makes Authorize in web api useless until you fix it. I would think that if they put the time in to make a Web Api security model of this complexity that surely they would want to provide at least some minimal working example that gets you up and going. I literally spent a week on this problem, it's ok now that the problem is solved, but it does give me cause for concern over documentation.

Comment: I kind of understand where you are coming from. But it will be tricky to provide a sort of a default implementation in OAuthAuthorizationProvider since the ValidateClientAuthentication method will need to know how to get the client details from somewhere  and similarly in the GenerateResourceOwnerCredentials method need custom code to check user from data stores.

Comment: True, for now I'm getting the client_id from the form values in the post. It would probably be better if it could be passed in the header, but I'm currently using the recommended method of passing in the grant_type and credentials in the post body.

Comment: I've never had this issue. However, the order of the GET parameters is important. It MUST be grant_type=password&username=urlPathEncodedvalue&password=urlPathEncodedvalue. Never had an issue passing Bearer tokens to [Authorize] decorated endpoints. So, fyi, if you're sending parameters out of order :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a little more supplemental information here for anyone who might be struggling with this issue where you want to access MVC5 / Web Api 2 from a client like UWP or Xamarin, but you need to lock down areas of your Web Api with the Authorize attribute.

The high level process is, instead of going through any MVC controllers you're going to do a POST directly to the /Token endpoint (or whatever endpoint specified).

First thing's first, if you want to do SSL for development but don't have a cert yet, go ahead and run the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpressadmincmd setupSslUrl -url:https://localhost:55970/ -UseSelfSigned
```

Where 55970 is the port of whatever your local website port is, I'll be referring to this in my text.

Next thing to do is be sure and override ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs on the client validation and resource granting methods, otherwise you'll run into invalid client or invalid grant errors.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        try
        {

            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);


            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string str = ex.ToString();
        }

        db.Dispose();
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId = "";
        string clientSecret = "";
        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);

        List<string> validClients = new List<string>(){ "web","Alliance_UWP","Alliance_Xamarin","Alliance_Web" };
        if (validClients.Contains(clientId))
            context.Validated();
    }
```

You don't need to be as verbose as I was on the allowed clients, just "web" is fine, you'll include that in your Http POST method as a url-encoded form value, along with grant_type = "password" and your username/password. Here's a quick and dirty UWP client I wrote which just takes in a username/password and accesses a dataset I have via the api that's tied down with an Authorize attribute. If you don't authenticate you'll get an authorization error, which is exactly what we want.

Just a note here that in my client I filter out self-signed certificate errors because I've set up a self-signed cert in IIS Express via the above command.

```
    Uri tokenUri = new Uri(@"https://localhost:55970/Token");
    // This is a test data set from my Web Api pulling data from 
    // Entity Framework and SQL Server protected by the Authorize attribute
    Uri testCasesUri = new Uri(@"https://localhost:55970/api/Cases");
    string accessToken = "";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btn_SubmitLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txt_User.Text;
        string password = txt_Password.Password;

        HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.RevocationFailure);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("client_id", "web");
        parameters.Add("grant_type", "password");
        parameters.Add("username", username);
        parameters.Add("password", password);
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(tokenUri, new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
            string jsonResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // TokenResult is a custom model class for deserialization of the Token Endpoint
            // Be sure to include Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet
            var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResult>(jsonResult);
            accessToken = resultObject.AccessToken;

            // When setting the request for data from Web Api set the Authorization
            // header to Bearer and the token you retrieved
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            result = await client.GetAsync(testCasesUri);
            jsonResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string debugBreak = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Hope that helps any of you guys having trouble getting Xamarin or UWP working with Web Api.